# Conditional statement in dataGridView Search

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, winforms

I have a dataGridView which gets filled with data returned from a query on button_Click. If the query returns no results I want to display a MessageBox that says so.

Is there a way of checking to see if the dataGridView is empty?

```
 private void SrchONeg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-112OILD\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DDK;Integrated Security=True");
            String query = "SELECT * FROM Davaoci WHERE DatumPoslednjegDavanja >= DATEADD(month, CASE WHEN Pol = 'M' THEN -3 ELSE -4 END, GETDATE()) AND KrvnaGrupa = 'ONeg' ORDER BY DatumPoslednjegDavanja ASC";
            SqlCommand SearchONeg = new SqlCommand(query, cs);
            SqlDataAdapter SearchONegDA = new SqlDataAdapter(SearchONeg);
            DataTable SearchONegDT = new DataTable();
            SearchONegDA.Fill(SearchONegDT);
            DgPretraga.DataSource = SearchONegDT;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why even let it try to populate your DataGridView if the DataTable itself is not populated?

```
if(SearchONegDT.Rows.Count > 0)
{
 DgPretraga.DataSource = SearchONegDT;
}
```

This way you're checking if your data exist before you even try to populate you're datagridview.

and

```
if(SearchONegDT.Rows.Count > 0)
{
 DgPretraga.DataSource = SearchONegDT;
}
else 
{
 // Your Message
}
```

Comment: Where do I incorporate this into my code?

Comment: put it in you button click function where you are trying to set your DgPretraga.DataSource = SearchONegDT; for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a `DataGridView` is empty by seeing how many rows are in it, like so:

```
if (dataGridView.Rows != null && dataGridView.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    //empty
}
```

Also make sure you have `AllowUserToAddRows` set to false, otherwise this method can fail.

[`DataGridView` Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: If you can just help me with how do I incorporate into my code? #noob Thanks